# How to send multipart form data with React (Next) / Redux / Saga?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, multipartform-data, redux-saga, saga

I am sending img file with usual React Saga and Next.js. I never worked with sending multipart form data so I don't know how to do it. I usually send image in a body in base64 format.

This is UI part:

```
const onUploadLogo = (e) => {
  var img = e.target.files[0]
  let formData = new FormData()
  formData.append("file", img)
  console.log('image check => ', img)
  console.log('formData check => ', formData)
  updateLogoFunc({ // this is the API call
    formData // body
  })
}

<label className="custom-file-upload">
  <input type="file" onChange={onUploadLogo} accept="image/*" />
  Attach
</label>
```

In `'image check => '` I see that my image is uploaded, I see the file, however `'formData check => '` gives me `undefined`. Just fyi, saga call of API works just fine, no problem with that. If you need the code of saga:

```
export function* updateLogoSaga(action) {
  try {
    yield put(setLoader(true))
    const response = yield ApiStore.garage.post(`UpdateLogo`, action.values)
    yield put(setLoader(false))
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(setLoader(false))
  }
}
```

My problem is I do not know how to send this damn image as `multipart form data` by POST call.

Comment: how are you handling this post in the backend?

Comment: @Yilmaz I don't know I do only my front-end part. They just sent me the Swagger, where it's written that I need to send body in multipart form data.

Comment: What are  `formData check => ` and `image check =>`

Comment: @Yilmaz it's console.log() in the code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var img = e.target.files[0]
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", img);
```

So far you got the file, but it is important how you are going to send it to the server.

If you need to send a buffer

```
 const buffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
```

or as bytes

```
// each entry of array should contain 8 bits
const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
```

So now your data is ready, you have to send it to the server. But it is not clear how you are going to send it to the server. are you going to send the image separete from other form inputs (In some case you might verify the image so you handle it separately). If you are going to send the image with form, together with other inputs inside a `submitHandler` it is better you write the above code inside `onChange`, set the file as state value and inside `submitHandler` you dispatch the input values. So far is the process of handling the image.

In saga, you have to create an action with type and your saga store would be listening to that type and once it receives that type, it will call the `updateLogoSaga` and your  `updateLogoSaga` is seems correct.

Comment: I don't think this provides answer to the question. What should I do next, what exactly should I send as a BODY?